# gnome3: Disable dialog for NFS devices

Tags: gnome, mount, nfs

I am mounting 3 NFS devices via fstab. As soon I log in, I am getting the following dialog for each NFS device:

[image: NFS dialog]

How can I disable this dialog only for NFS devices, but not for USB devices (as USB stics or USB hard disks)?

Comment: When to the filesystems mount - during boot or during login?

Comment: It mounts via fstab during the boot, but the window appears after I log in with my user.

Answer (score 0):

For all devices, look in the details dialog *(On heavily edited Gnome 3.8)*:

[image: Details]

Don't know how to do it for specific media though - looking in [dconf-editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/dconf-tools/) probably might help.

Comment: "only for NFS devices, but not for USB devices"

Comment: Yes, that is why I linked to dconf editor, as that might have advanced options.

Comment: Ooh, found something. Get dconf, and look in `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling`. You have to enter the 'x-content' type for NFS devices. Then it should work. See, told you so =).

Comment: Also, needs to be entered in this format: `['x-content/image-dcf', 'x-content/audio-player']` . If you find any of this useful @Dennis, I could add it to my answer.

Comment: I don't get how to use `x-content` to disable only NFS devices...

Comment: You have to find the x-content type for x-content devices, sort of like the [mimetype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimetype#Type_application), but not the same as. The problem is, what is the x-content type of NFS devices... That I can't help you on sorry, but you could post another question on it.